# State inside parent component not setting initial value. Child component is preventing it from working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Child component is passing data as prop via function to Parent. Inside Parent I have a variable with a string value. I also have a useState. The initial value of that useState should be the string value.
But for some reason setting the initial value to the variable doesn't render the state initial value.

```
const header = () => {
        //some data I fetched
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");

        //take the string I need
    let city = address.split(", ")[0];

        //initiate the useState with the string above
    const [updateAddress, setUpdateAddress] = useState(city);

    //accept new location from SearchLocation component and pass it to the address
    const handleChangeLocation = (userInput) => {
        setUpdateAddress(userInput);
    };
  
         //won't render the value of updateAddress which is the city I passed
         return (<div className={styles.city}>{updateAddress}</div>
                <SearchLocation changeLocation={handleChangeLocation} />)
}
```

When I add a primitive value to the city variable  or the useState for testing purposes it won't render either.

If I go to the child component(SearchLocation) that transfers the data I need to the parent component and, I remove the prop the city variable in the parent component, the city value will get through fine.

I would appreciate some explanation. Thank you

--

Comment: What explanation are you looking for? `address` is an empty string, `address.split(", ")` returns an array with a single element with value `""`, and this is the value for the initial `updateAddress` state value.

Comment: Hi drew, When I log city under the line ```    let city = address.split(", ")[0];``` I get the correct value. which is the string that I am expecting. But passing that value to the ```useState(city)``` won't give me what anything when I log the ```updateAddress```. So the value isn't passing through.

Comment: What is the "correct value" you are referring to? I just explained that `address` is an empty string and so `city` will also be an empty string. Are you later updating the `address` state and for some reason you expect the `updateAddress` state to also change? Is this really a [mcve] of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I did it based on what you said you needed.

You update a state directly in the root of the component since it's asynchronous, you have to update them inside a `useEffect` hook. Especially if the initial data is fetched from an API.

Your code below wouldn't work.

```
....
//take the string I need
let city = address.split(", ")[0];

//initiate the useState with the string above
const [updateAddress, setUpdateAddress] = useState(city);
...
```

Anyway here's what I did, so based from your code an address is in the format of ***city, xxxx, xxxx***, so you need to get the ***[0]*** index.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// make sure your component starts with a capital letter
const Header = () => {
  // assign the search keyword to a different state
  const [searchKeyword, setSearchKeyword] = useState('')
  // then the specific data you want
  const [addressCity, setAddressCity] = useState('')

  // Setting the initial address from the API
  // You need to put updating of the state inside a useEffect or what because it is asynchronous
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch from the api
    // assign the fetched data to the address state
    const addressFromAPI = 'Test, address'
    setAddressCity(addressFromAPI.split(', ')[0])
  }, [])

  // Add a onChange handler for the search input
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    // assign the input of the user to the search keyword state
    const userInput = e.target.value
    setSearchKeyword(userInput)

    // now get what you wanted, the city
    const city = userInput.split(', ')[0]
    console.log(city)
    setAddressCity(city)
  }

  // now everything works
  return <>
    <div>Search keyword: {searchKeyword}</div>
    <div>City: {addressCity}</div>
    <input onChange={handleSearch} value={searchKeyword} />
  </>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Header />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

here's a screenshot

[image]

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to achieve, please let me know if it is or give us more info about your problem:)

Btw it seems like you are in the early stage of developing in react, reminds me of the days. Maybe you could try reading the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) or this [free course from scrimba](https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact)

Comment: Hey thank you.
To be honest.. It wasn't a react thing. I was missing a if statement. After hours of debugging I figured it out. 

Yes I am a junior dev starting to learn react now. Thanks  though

Comment: What do you mean not a react thing? 

Though btw honestly, the code is kinda messy. But pretty sure it will improve.

Hope you take into consideration the performance and stuff. If you don't do things properly in react it might be rendering endlessly or multiple times unnecessarily in the background.

The impact might not be noticeable at if the project is small but it will greatly affect everything the more the codebase grows